# An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden in airflow (2.0.0)+

Tags: amazon-s3, airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver

Error -

```
*** Failed to verify remote log exists s3://airflow_test/airflow-logs/demo/task1/2022-05-13T18:20:45.561269+00:00/1.log.
An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

Dockerfile -

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.2.3

COPY /airflow/requirements.txt /requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /requirements.txt

RUN pip install apache-airflow[crypto,postgres,ssh,s3,log]

USER root

# Update aptitude with new repo
RUN apt-get update

# Install software 
RUN apt-get install -y git

USER airflow
```

Under connection UI -

```
Connection Id *          - aws_s3_log_storage
Connection Type *        - S3
Host                     - <My company's internal link>. (ex - https://abcd.company.com)
Extra                    - {"aws_access_key_id": "key", "aws_secret_access_key": "key", "region_name": "us-east-1"}
```

Under values.yaml -

```
config:
    logging:
        remote_logging: 'True'
        remote_base_log_folder: 's3://airflow_test/airflow-logs'
        remote_log_conn_id: 'aws_s3_log_storage'
        logging_level: 'INFO'
        fab_logging_level: 'WARN'
        encrypt_s3_logs: 'False'
        host: '<My company's internal link>. (ex - https://abcd.company.com)'
        colored_console_log: 'False'
```

How did I created the bucket?

Installed awscli

used the commands -

```
1. aws configure
    AWS Access Key ID: <access key>

    AWS Secret Access Key: <secret key>

    Default region name: us-east-1

    Default output format: 

2. aws s3 mb s3://airflow_test --endpoint-url=<My company's internal link>. (ex - https://abcd.company.com)
```

I am not getting a clue on how to resolve the error. I am actually very new to airflow and helm charts.

Comment: `An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden` - your AWS access key ID & AWS secret access key does not have the right permissions. Add the `s3:HeadObject` permission for your target S3 bucket to your IAM user/role.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I ll try this. 
I had one more doubt, will company's internal link (endpoint url) provided in values.yaml file under "host" key works?

Comment: That's a separate question, let's solve this one first in a focused manner and then feel free to open a new question if you have more 

Answer (score 1):

I had same error message with you. your account or Key might not have enough permission for accessing S3 bucket.
Please check your role has enough permissions below.

"s3:PutObject*",
"s3:PutObjectAcl",
"s3:PutObjectVersionAcl",
"s3:GetObject*",
"s3:ListObject*",
"s3:ListBucket*",
"s3:PutBucket*",
"s3:GetBucket*",
"s3:DeleteObject